# Solve for $n$ in $(4/3) ^n = 6439 / 3072 $

Tags: algebra-precalculus, logarithms, exponential-function

It is a series and sequences question. I worked it up to here but I'm stuck at this point.
$$\left(\dfrac{4}{3}\right)^n = \dfrac{6439}{3072}$$ Solve for $n$. Thanks

Answer (score 5):

$\left(\dfrac{4}{3}\right)^n=\dfrac{6439}{3072}\\\implies\log \left(\dfrac{4}{3}\right)^n=\log \dfrac{6439}{3072}\\\implies n\cdot \log\dfrac{4}{3}=\log \dfrac{6439}{3072}\\\implies n=\dfrac{\log \dfrac{6439}{3072}}{\log\dfrac{4}{3}}\\\implies n= 2.572438483$

Comment: +1 why didn't you do that by MAPLE? :-)